# SimpleDateFormat with Calendar giving wrong date

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, formatter

I have the following Code that updates my Calendar object.

```
val date = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
    myCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR))
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, myCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND))
    updateDate()
}
```

I receive the following values:

```
year = 2019
month = 11
day = 31
```

But when I execute the following code i obtain year = 2020:

```
private fun updateDate()
{
    val myFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    date_et.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.time))
}
```

`myCalendar.time` gives me the following string: `Tue Dec 31 11:47:00 GMT+01:00 2019`

But on `date_et` appears the following one: `31/12/2020 11:47:00`

> Why I have 2019 on Calendar and appears 2020 on my view?

Comment: val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" - replace Y to "y"

Comment: @Nik with yyyy it's working. Why?

Comment: ah,With the simple date format (myDateTime. format('MM/dd/YYYY h:mm a')), the year increases here is your prob

Comment: @Lechucico 

@"YYYY" is week-based calendar year.

@"yyyy" is ordinary calendar year.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: (A) Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. (B) You *really* should be moving on to *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
val myFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
```

To

```
val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```